# Detect Android Camera folder

Tags: android, camera, directory

I would like to detect the camera folder on every Android device. From what I've read this folder differs from an manufacturer to another and there is no guarantee that there will be even an DCIM folder on the device.

This is the method that I'm using to get the files now:

```
private static final Set<String> FILTER_FOLDERS = new HashSet<String>(
        Arrays.asList(new String[] { "camera", "100andro", "100media" }));


private Set<String> getCameraPictures() {
        final String[] columns = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE };
        // Order by options - by date & descending
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN
                + " DESC";
        // Stores all the images from the gallery in Cursor
        final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, // base URI for
                                                                // the Images
                columns, // Which columns to return
                null, // Which rows to return (all rows)
                null, // Selection arguments (none)
                orderBy); // Ordering

        // Total number of images
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        // Create an array to store path to all the images
        String[] picturesPath = new String[count];

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int dataColumn = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            int bucketColumn = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

            do {
                if (FILTER_FOLDERS.contains(cursor.getString(bucketColumn)
                        .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()))) {
                    // Store the path of the image
                    picturesPath[cursor.getPosition()] = cursor
                            .getString(dataColumn);
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // Close the cursor
        if (null != cursor) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(picturesPath));
    }
```

But this is returning images from other places also ... 
How can I retrieve only the images taken with the camera ?
If there is no native way to do this, where can I find what are the names for the folders used by each manufacturer (as many as there are) so that I can filter it by BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME ?

Thank you

LE:

I have updated the method to get the images on device & also filter the folders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are dozens, perhaps hundreds, of camera apps that ship with devices, to go along with thousands of camera apps available for download. None have to use a particular "camera folder" and none have to have their images indexed by `MediaStore`.

The conventional "camera folder" for a device will be in the location specified by `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`. That directory might not exist yet, if no camera app has used it. But, again, there is no requirement that a camera app use it -- they can store their images wherever they want to, including places that you cannot access (e.g., internal storage, "the cloud").

> How can I retrieve only the images taken with the camera ?

You can't. There are well over one billion smartphones on the planet, and any phone could have pictures on it taken by any camera from any other phone, courtesy of photo-sharing apps and sites. This is on top of pictures taken by cameras other than smartphones. There is no requirement that images taken by the device's own camera need to be somehow designated as such for your benefit.

Comment: I think there should be some methods to achieve this. At least to cover most of the devices. I am thinking about cloud applications, which have the functionality for autobackup photos, and they backup only photos taken with the device's camera ... 
If you have any suggestion that would be great :)... Thank you

Comment: @IonutNegru: "At least to cover most of the devices" -- that would be `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`, as noted in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I tried using that and I got the same results with the method I used.... It includes other images that were not taken with the camera... For now I filter through them by checking with some hard coded folder names like "camera" or "100andro"...but this is just temporary until I find a more solid solution... I will update my code tomorrow with the new method... Still, thank you for the answer and for your time!

Comment: @IonutNegru: "It includes other images that were not taken with the camera" -- any app is allowed to put images inside that folder.

Comment: I know, and the only method that partially works is to filter through the folders :(... But I saw google autobackup, saving only images taken with the camera... You have any ideea how they did that ?

Comment: I chose to get all images from the device because there is no safe way to detect only the images taken with an camera application. 
@CommonsWare I will mark your answer as correct because it presented and explained to me all the issues and some ways to detect the images.
Thank you