# How to get the default directory of photo made by camera in android?

Tags: android, camera, android-sdcard

I hope to get the default directory of photo made by camera in android.

I think that the Code A can do that, and `/storage/sdcard0/DCIM` is displayed in log,

but in  fact, my photos made by camera are stored in the folder `/storage/extSdCard/DCIM`

How can I get the default directory of photo made by camera in android? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
File dir10 = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
Log.e("MainActivity", "getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() 10:" + dir10.toString());
```

**More**

It seems that the default storage location of photos made by camera is set by user, sometimes it's Memory card, somtimes it's SD card. I hope know which storage location the user selected for store photos made by camera.

[image]

Comment: What is the device OS version ?

Comment: OS: 4.1.2 And  5.1

Comment: It seems that default disk of photos made by camera  are setup by user

Comment: It seems that you are looking for this . [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993213/how-can-i-find-out-the-camera-images-folder-of-an-android-phone)

Answer (score 15):

Use **`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`**
with parameter DIRECTORY_PICTURES

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(path, "DemoPicture.jpg");
```

**DIRECTORY_DCIM** 
is the traditional location for pictures and videos when mounting the device as a camera.

**DIRECTORY_PICTURES** 
is Standard directory in which to place pictures that are available to the user.

Hope it helps !

Comment: It seems that the default storage location of photos made by camera is set by user, sometimes it's Memory card, sometimes it's SD card. I hope know which storage location the user set for store photos made by camera.

Comment: Make sure to enable access to the external storage first before using the camera. you can found this on https://guides.codepath.com/android/Managing-Runtime-Permissions-with-PermissionsDispatcher

Answer (score 5):

#### 1.This will work only if user didn't change the default Camera output Dir

As per documentation, There are two options

> DIRECTORY_DCIM
>   The traditional location for pictures and videos when mounting the device as a camera.

```
File musicDirectory = new File( getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM));
```

> DIRECTORY_PICTURES
>   Standard directory in which to place pictures that are available to the user.

```
File musicDirectory = new File( getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
```

**getExternalFilesDir()** will return **File** object

you can refer here [developer page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)

#### 2. There is another trick you can do if you have atleast taken one pic taken in camera

```
String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE};     
final Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"); 
if(cursor != null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    //you can access last taken pics here. 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code can work, but is there the more better way?

Comment: i don't know other ways

Comment: Thanks! I test your code 2 again, I found it's not correct. If I copy a image from my PC to Mobile phone, the image is hit by  your code 2, but in fact, the image isn't taken via camera

Comment: sorry i mentioned in code 2 it only works if you have taken images from your mobile camera, risks involved if you use that method

Comment: Thanks!

By http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428866/detect-android-camera-folder  

it seems that none can get Android Camera folder, right?

Comment: Deprecated from Android API 16. use CursorLoader instead.

Answer (score 3):

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` is used to get directories on internal storage only.

To get the DCIM folder on your secondary storage (if exists) you need to follow this code:

```
String secondStorage = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
File file = new File(secStore + "/DCIM");
File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
```

Comment: My Sony X compact has an SD card, but `SECONDARY_STORAGE` is not set.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DefaultMediaRepository implements MediaRepository {
private final AppCompatActivity activity;
private LoaderManager supportLoaderManager;

DefaultMediaRepository(@NotNull AppCompatActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    supportLoaderManager = activity.getSupportLoaderManager();
}

public void media(int offset, CompletedListener<List<Media>> completedListener) {
    supportLoaderManager.initLoader((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), null,
            new MediaLoader(offset, completedListener));

}

class MediaLoader implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private static final int LIMIT = 20;
    private Uri uri;
    private String selection;
    private String[] selectionArgs;
    private String sortOrder;
    private CompletedListener<List<Media>> completedListener;

    MediaLoader(int offset, CompletedListener<List<Media>> completedListener) {
        this.completedListener = completedListener;
        uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        selection = "("
                + FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE
                + " OR "
                + FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
                + ")"
                + " AND "
                + ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
                + " = ?";
        selectionArgs = new String[]{"Camera"};
        sortOrder = ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC " +
                " LIMIT " + LIMIT + " offset " + offset;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(activity.getApplicationContext(), uri, null, selection,
                selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, @NotNull Cursor cursor) {
        @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays") List<Media> list = new LinkedList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FileColumns._ID));
            int media = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE));
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(this.uri, "" + id);
            list.add(new Media(uri.toString(), media == FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO));
        }
        cursor.close();
        completedListener.completed(list);
        supportLoaderManager.destroyLoader(loader.getId());
    }
}
}
```