# Consistently load photos (taken by camera) from MediaStore, across Android vendors

Tags: android, camera, android-sdcard, photos, mediastore

I want to query the `MediaStore` for all photos on the device, but only those taken by the camera. Please note the distinction I'm trying to make on *photos* vs any other image media (downloads, screenshots etc) on the device. The `MediaStore` contains many different directories, or "buckets", where the default camera/pictures location is one of them. However, there doesn't seem to be any standard on what this bucket is named -- on my Sony Z5, it's "100ANDRO", on my Samsung Galaxy S3, it's simply "Camera".

Reading various [posts on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428866/detect-android-camera-folder), it seems this varies with manufactorer, but I should be able to find the path to the conventional "camera folder" at

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
```

So I can filter the query to `MediaStore` on that path (e.g. `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM` on my S3). If the user chooses to store the photos at a totally unconventional location, perhaps using a third-party camera app, then that's OK. I'm only hoping to cover the most "normal" use cases here.

**But what if I want to load also the photos on an external SD card, if present?**

As far as I can see, the photos on the "internal memory" and those on the SD card will have the same `BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` (and `BUCKET_ID`) in the `MediaStore`. But getting the *path* to the SD card photos directory seems to be very difficult across devices.

So what do you think about this approach (to get all photos):

1. find the "camera folder" path (as above)
2. query the `MediaStore`, filtered on this path. Find the corresponding `BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME`
3. query the `MediaStore` *again*, filtered on `BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` from step 2, and where the path differs from that in step 2.

Step 2 will find all the photos on the internal memory. 
Step 3 will find any photos on the SD card, if present.
Step 3 will be empty if no card is mounted, or if it contains no photos, so this *might seem* to be a rather graceful approach.

Comment: "But getting the path to the SD card photos directory seems to be very difficult across devices" -- there is no filesystem path to removable storage that is useful for you. Generally speaking, you do not have arbitrary filesystem access to removable storage.

Comment: Yes. So what do you think of my proposed approach, where I try to work around not having a path?

Comment: I haven't tried anything like that, so I have no idea how well it will hold up in reality.

Comment: I see. Well, in case you have some tips on how to achieve what I'm trying to go (essentially, "just" load all photos on the device) then please do let me know. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Well, to be completely honest... when I read the opening sentence of your question, my immediate reaction was "there's no reliable way to do that". You seem to be prepared for that, such as your willingness to ignore camera apps that store in unexpected locations. But will your users understand this, if your app basically fails to find anything because their device or camera app behaves outside your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

> So I can filter the query to `MediaStore` on that path (e.g. `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM` on my S3)

You can achieve that with the code in that link you found, it's the best solution you'll find, yet, like others have said, you have no guarantee that the device's camera app is actually storing pictures inside a directory at `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM`, and there's even the problem that other apps might also be using it to store any images, other than pictures, since it's public...

Comment: Thanks for the response! I realize this is a difficult thing to do in Android. However, in an effort to clarify, here's what I want to do. I want to load the images (preferrably the "photos") on the device. If other images show up too, then that's OK. So I guess I should just show *all* the images in the MediaStore, and maybe let the user filter away certain buckets?

Comment: Furthermore, the app I'm writing updates JPEG files (with metadata). If the image happens to be on an SD card, then my app gets "Permission Denied" even if it holds the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. I understand writing to the SD card (after Android 4.4) requires an entirely different approach than writing to internal memory, which is why I need a way to discern between images on the internal memory, and images on the external memory. Actually, I was not expecting all of this complexity -- but it's all part of the challenge :D

Comment: That's a good way to solve it, querying for JPEG files only and then let the user filter out the ones he/she doesn't wish updated.